# Given specific of an iterative code prove it with program correctness

Tags: algorithms

[image]

(a) Given an appropiate loop invariant

(b) Use your loop invariant from (a) to prove partial correctness (when loop terminates)

(c) Define an appropriate expression for the purpose of proving termination.

---

Solution:

a)

(1) $0 \leq i \leq j$

(2) not sure

(b)

Suppose the loop terminates

By $LI(1)$ $i \leq j$

By loop exit condition $i \geq j$

hence $i = j$ (*)

Not sure how to solve rest

(c)

$e = j - i + 1$ (pretty sure this is right)

How do I do this?